# Need help configuring ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, configuration, installation, imagemagick

I've directly downloaded the tar file from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php?ImageMagick=9sonkfolbtqvafmpc5b9v8fdm7) onto my desktop for Mac OSX (which is what I'm using) and extracted its contents. Now I've read the following instructions on how to set it up, but honestly they're a bit too cryptic for me. I was wondering if anyone could please break down these instructions into simpler, bite size pieces for someone who typically has trouble configuring new things...

I'd truly appreciate any help! Thanks!

Btw, my end goal is to set this up for the Paperclip plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) if you don't have it already. Once MacPorts is installed it should be fairly straightforward based on the instructions listed at the link you provided.

`sudo port install ImageMagick`

For others interested in this topic, I might look into installing [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) instead of MacPorts.

Comment: i installed MacPorts, when I run `sudo port install ImageMagick` I get `sudo: port: command not found`

Comment: If you had a terminal window open while you installed MacPorts, close it and quit the terminal process. Launch a new terminal and you should be good to go.

Comment: after it's installed, what should I do? The instructions at the link I provided are actually confusing for me...

Comment: Those instructions are for manually installing the binary I believe. Does `convert` work from the terminal? (you may have to restart terminal again after the install)

Comment: ahh ok so MacPorts does everything for me? Pretty sweet. I'm still waiting for ImageMagick to finish installation. I'll let you know.